# Is there a way to simplify O(n^c) · O(c^n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to simplify O(*n*<sup>*c*</sup>) · O(*c*<sup>*n*</sup>) but couldn't come up with anything. Is this equal to infinity, or would it fall under one of the more common type of complexities (O(*n*), O(*n*<sup>*c*</sup>), O(*c*<sup>*n*</sup>), O(*n* log *n*), O(log *n*) or O(n!))?

Answer (score 2):

O(*n*<sup>*c*</sup>) · O(*c*<sup>*n*</sup>) means the set of functions that can be expressed as *f*(*n*) · *g*(*n*) where *f*(*n*) ∈ O(*n*<sup>*c*</sup>) and *g*(*n*) ∈ O(*c*<sup>*n*</sup>).

Since *n*<sup>*c*</sup> ∈ O((1+δ)<sup>*n*</sup>) for arbitrarily small positive δ, we have O(1<sup>*n*</sup>) ⊂ O(*n*<sup>*c*</sup>) ⊂ O((1+δ)<sup>*n*</sup>). (Do you see why?)

Additionally, it's a general property of big-O notation that O(foo) · O(bar) = O(foo · bar); so we can always move multiplication inside the O (or pull multiplication outside the O). (Do you see why?)

Combining these two observations, we have O(*c*<sup>*n*</sup>) ⊂ O(*n*<sup>*c*</sup>) · O(*c*<sup>*n*</sup>) ⊂ O((*c*+δ)<sup>*n*</sup>) for arbitrarily small positive δ. So you can reasonably simplify O(*n*<sup>*c*</sup>) · O(*c*<sup>*n*</sup>) to O((*c*+δ)<sup>*n*</sup>). This is analogous to how O(*n* log *n*) is sometimes called "quasilinear", because it's a subset of O(*n*<sup>1+δ</sup>) for arbitrarily small positive δ.

Answer (score 1):

e^N grows faster then all functions from your list of asymptotically equivalent candidates.
To find out whether g(N) = E^n*n^E and f(N) = e^N have the same order of grows we need the limit of g(N)/f(N) -> 1 when N->infinity. But:
[image]

So given function doesn't fall under one of the more common type of complexities (O(n), O(nc), O(cn), O(n log n), O(log n)) - it grows faster.
Following log log plot illustrates and compares order of grows of mentioned functions:

[image]

Some algorithms has exponential brute force solution but may be simplified(restrictions added) and become faster. The brute force solution of the traveling salesman problem is O(n!) which is approximately O(N^N).

Nowadays input with N = 30 is solvable in minutes for 2^N. For N = 1..30 you can observe behavior of c^n*n^c and c^N using following loglog plot:

[image]